# What is the correct and secure way to handle url routing in php?

Tags: php, url-routing

I saw some tutorial websites doing like this.

**Menu URL**

```
www.website.com/view/method=emp_master&task=edit
```

**In php file**

```
$file= isset($_GET['method'])? filter_input(INPUT_GET,$_GET['method'],FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS) : ''
$task = isset($_GET['task']) ? filter_input(INPUT_GET,$_GET['task'],FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS):''
require_once('./views/'.$file.'.php?mode='.$task);
```

Then it loads the relevant page.

*I don't know how the professionals named this function.I am calling it page routing.you are welcome to edit the title*

1. How can we improve this ?
2. Are there any methods to accomplish something like this the proper way?

**I want to do this without any framworks**

Comment: You can do it by add ".htaccess" file with your web site, or by any "php framework+htaccess"

Comment: `require_once('./views/'.$file.'.php?mode='.$task);` – that is wrong in any case; in the file system, there is no query string.

Comment: @CBroe So how to use `require_once()` with `$file` and `$task`

Comment: By requiring the file by file path/name only, it will automatically have access to all variables that are in the scope that the require statement is in.

Comment: @CBroe that mean `require_once('./views/'.$file.'.php)` can use?

Comment: Yes, but not without further checks on the filename value – otherwise, _every_ PHP file that you have could be included, and you probably don’t want that. (Research keyword: path traversal)